# sort describe table foo output by field alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, explain

I have a sizeable table that I'm actively working on and modifying columns of. It'd be handy if I could sort a `describe table` by Field name alphabetically to quickly find the definition for a column. The docs for mysql `describe` nor `explain` mention anything about sorting. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DESCRIBE and SHOW COLUMNS don't have an option to sort their results. You can read more about them here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-columns.html

If you want a customized list of columns of a table, you can query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE, COLUMN_DEFAULT, IS_NULLABLE
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='mydatabase' AND TABLE_NAME='mytable';
```

Read more about this table here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/columns-table.html

Comment: yep, querying the information_schema was going to be plan 'b', but it's sure as hell nasty!

Comment: An alternative is to run DESCRIBE, save it to a file, and run `sort` on the file. I use shell tools to fiddle with query output like that *constantly*.

Comment: interesting! i'll select this as the answer as it provides a (possibly, the) solution

Comment: I'm assuming you are on a Linux or Mac environment and have access to a decent shell and the `sort` command. If you're on Windows, you're on your own. :-)

Comment: yep, I couldn't imagine running mysql on a windows platform - even for dev - but KISS, I'll go with the information_schema table. Thanks!